# JAX-RS and custom authorization

Tags: java, jax-rs, restful-authentication

I'm trying to secure the JAX-RS endpoint and am currently trying to figure out how the authentication and authorization work. Most examples are quite simple as they only piggyback from Java EE App-Server role via web.xml.

I'm wondering how to use something else than the Java EE AS roles. For example: I'd like to use session or some sort of token (or some sort of identifier).

Answer (score 7):

It all depends upon the JAX-RS implementation you're using. I'm using [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/index.html) on embedded [Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Documentation).

```
SecurityHandler sh = new SecurityHandler();

// the UserRealm is the collection of users, and a mechanism to determine if
// provided credentials are valid
sh.setUserRealm(new MyUserRealm());

// the Authenticator is a strategy for extracting authentication credentials
// from the request. BasicAuthenticator uses HTTP Basic Auth
sh.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator());
```

See [How to Configure Security with Embedded Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+Configure+Security+with+Embedded+Jetty)

Once you have the `Principal` in the `HttpServletRequest`, you can inject these into the context of the JAX-RS request.

```
public abstract class AbstractResource {
    private Principal principal;
    @Context
    public void setSecurityContext(SecurityContext context) {
        principal = context.getUserPrincipal();
    }
    protected Principal getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }
}

@Path("/some/path")
public class MyResource extends AbstractResource {
    @GET
    public Object get() {
        Principal user = this.getPrincipal();
        // etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: Don't role your own security framework unless you really, really, really, need one.

Look at what the [OAuth filter](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/tags/jersey-1.17/jersey/contribs/jersey-oauth/oauth-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/oauth/server/api/OAuthServerFilter.java) in Jersey does. It reads the Authorization header which holds credentials in a different format than those normally understood (HTTP Basic). It'll turn those credentials into roles which you can then use to implement security (@RolesAllowed) if you add in the [Roles Allowed Filter](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory.java) which does the actually enforcement. Try looking at how those filters work.